# How to bypass Error 1020 Access Denied in PHP?

Tags: php, json, cloudflare, cloudflare-apps

I want to access JSON Code available at following URL:

https://feurl.com/api/source/65xdjs0eg84nlpr

JSON Code is:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "type": "mp4",
      "file": "https://fvs.io/redirector?token=M1drdW5iSCtSc2RoQWZEQk90dU9pTzFoeTNMOUd4M3ZaY2xVZnczOHdMZ1ljRHlqNzh2RThPaE1wSTBtTU9udWp0eHVDaCs4d1NtbGRTbFlWeHJyV25QY1JrR3Q3MFVBS0R5ZWoxMUJZZVpnNS8wVFRsaFZPditsMENtQ0UvZ1FsSmFvNkFtYTl0YlBJRkw5bnBkdzduemRSZU5jS1hUQjNmdXI6NXlwZVJxR2VlaUFLQTdSRFRRWnQ1dz09",
      "label": "480p"
    },
    {
      "type": "mp4",
      "file": "https://fvs.io/redirector?token=UUVYbHFDUHh2dDAvbVppR1A1UEJZV2FYd1k2ODRYdHJFRVFxWGZGZEFncUNnOFVkOVhOenI5bW14dXpleXVVbnZLbk5FRjJPbEZ6Mzc3Y0k3cTQ1a1Q3cDA4V0xuWWwwa0lVVVcyeEhvOXRray9wejVETVRWOE9MSnNsM0ZVQUltNlRYQnZueWRvb3pQNWNOUzB6UENYNGRsWmdaU0RXV1NVajE6WlRnbEFRR1doL29kaFl4UzVoZVI4Zz09",
      "label": "720p"
    }
  ],
  "success": true,
  "is_vr": false,
  "captions": []
}
```

But it shows Error 1020. I am trying to fetch JSON data resting on above url. Butevery time it shows error 1020. How to access using PHP or CURL? Is their any possible way to access that site? Please note that clearing cookies or cache does not solve the problem.

Comment: You'll need to contact them, they can tell you why you're getting access denied. We don't know anything about their system.

Comment: Possibly you need to provide some kind of authentication in your request. Only the maintainers of the website can tell you that - or maybe they publish documentation which tells you what to do. There's no way to bypass that (or at least there shouldn't be) - if there was, what would be the point of having access controls, do you imagine?